# Static method List<T> properties not found

Tags: c#, list, generics, types

I am cleaning up so nasty code generation
they have classes in the UI (ASPX) for all the drop downs,
I first was able to change then to linq not I want a static method to pass the list

so the logic is off loaded out of the UI
here is what i have

All the lists I will pass have these properties below,
just new to writing Generic Methods using

```
public static string Get_GenericDisplayData_Data(IList<T> ilist)
        {
            var list = (from prop in ilist
                select new

                    Display = prop.Display ?? "",
                    Description = prop.Description ?? "",
                    Id = prop.Id
                }).ToList();

            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(list);
            return json;
        }
```

The compiler throws errors saying , Display, ID and Description do not exist or cannot be found, 
how to fix it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Edited the comments

Comment: You can fix it by typing `where T:{YouClassWithTheseFields}`

Comment: I don't follow, there are literally  close to 100 classes in this project with those properties

Comment: Possible, you could write `where T:dynamic`, but it's a curved hands approach... Or `IList<dynamic> ilist`

Comment: Why does it not compile? Well, let's take a simple example. Let's say you called this method with a `List<int>`. Does `int` have a `Display` property? (Of course, no it doesn't). **That is why it doesn't compile**. It doesn't matter if **you** know that every call to it will have those properties. **The compiler doesn't know that**. In practical terms, I'd suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48748604/generic-method-with-type-constraints-or-base-class-parameter and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters .

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already in the comment, you need to add a generic type constraint to tell the compiler that your type T is fully qualified for retriving these members.

You could have a large amount of classes, which should be the reason that you use generics, but at least they must have a base class that defines the Display, Description, and Id members, then using it as the constraint base class would make it compile, unless not all of your classes have these members therefore your code is logically incorrect.

```
where T : TheBaseClass
```

An alternative that is not so much recommanded is to use dynamic.

```
from dynamic item in items
select new
{
    Display = item.Display ?? "",
    Description = item.Description ?? "",
    Id = item.Id
}
```

It would throw runtime exception if the element type of the collection does not have these members.

Though runtime binding may lead to a bit lower performance.

Btw, your identifier naming is antipattern and the name does not represent the logical meaning of the variables. Use items and item respectively for the collection and its elements.